# What is the naming convention for java native interface method and module name?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am able to follow a jni tutorial just fine. But when I change the method name, I run into trouble. Is there a naming convention I need to follow? The tutorial used HelloJNI as the module name, and library name. I used "useaaacom".

Comment: The method name has to match the JNI function name.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html):

> Dynamic linkers resolve entries based on their names. A native method name is concatenated from the following components:
>
> - the prefix `Java_`
> - a mangled fully-qualified class name
> - an underscore (`_`) separator
> - a mangled method name
> - for overloaded native methods, two underscores (`__`) followed by the mangled argument signature

So if you have the following:

```
package com.foo.bar;

class Baz {
    public native void Grill(int i);
}
```

Then the corresponding C function should be:

```c
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_foo_bar_Baz_Grill(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint i);
```

If you have an underscore in the Java method name:

```java
public native void A_Grill(int i);
```

Then the C function would be:

```java
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_foo_bar_Baz_A_1Grill(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint i);
```

The `_1` escape sequence matches the `_` in `A_Grill`.

Answer (score 0):

You're free to call your package and class and methods whatever you like at the Java level, subject to the rules of the language, but the naming convention at the C level is completely defined by the output of the `javah` tool.

You can call the shared library whatever you like as well subject to filename rules and the rules of ’System.load()/loadLibrary()`.