# Find manually registered (obfuscated) native function address

Tags: android, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm trying to understand an Android app which contains a native method named `foo` in class `com.app.Bar`

Inside class `Bar` there is a static clause that loads a shared object `System.loadLibrary("libfoo.so")` which I assume is build with [-fvisibility=hidden](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#native-libraries) because the only export is `JNI_OnLoad`, no `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app_Bar_foo` which means `public native int foo` does not follow the [naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470463/is-the-naming-convention-for-java-native-interface-method-and-module-name).

1. What is the process when `foo` is [invoked](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SimpleJNI/jni/native.cpp#56) ?
2. How can I extract the address of `foo` ? I'm familiar with [Frida](https://frida.re)
3. Is there a way to output all `JNINativeMethod[] methods` ?

What have I tried so far ?

1. [JNIAnalyzer](https://github.com/maaaaz/jnianalyzer) outputs 13K lines that look like `JNI_OnLoad@@Base+0x712e`
2. Frida script to try to find `foo` address (did not work)

```js
function intercept(address) {
    try {
        Interceptor.attach(address, {
            onEnter: function(args) {
                console.log("onEnter", address);
            },
            onLeave: function(ignored) {}
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
function Main() {
    var dlopen = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName(null, 'dlopen'), 'pointer', ['pointer', 'int']);
    var dlsym = new NativeFunction(Module.findExportByName(null, 'dlsym'), 'pointer', ['pointer', 'pointer']);
    Process.enumerateModulesSync().forEach(function(m) {
        if (m.name === "libfoo.so") {
            console.log("Module", JSON.stringify(m));
            var handle = dlopen(Memory.allocUtf8String(m.path), 1);
            var symb = Memory.allocUtf8String("foo");
            var exports = Module.enumerateExportsSync(m.name);
            console.log(JSON.stringify({
                handle: handle,
                symb: symb,
                dlsym: dlsym(handle, symb),
                exports: exports.map(function(ex){ return ex.address + ": " + ex.name })
            }, null, 2));
            // intercept all exports
            exports.forEach(function(ex){
                intercept(ex.address);
            });
            // explicit intercept foo by known offset
            intercept(m.base.add(0x22334)); // this outputs "Error: unable to intercept function at 0x86c96328; please file a bug"
        }
    });

    console.log("sleep..");
    Thread.sleep(1.5);
    console.log("invoke", Java.use('com.clazz.foo').signToken("A".repeat(32)));
}
Java.perform(Main);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solved it using `Frida`

Hooking `art::JNI::RegisterNativeMethods(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, JNINativeMethod const*, int, bool)` and `art::JNI::FindClass` after `libart.so` module is loaded.

[Code](https://github.com/iddoeldor/frida-snippets/)

```
var RevealNativeMethods = function() {
  var pSize = Process.pointerSize;
  var env = Java.vm.getEnv();
  var RegisterNatives = 215, FindClassIndex = 6; // search "215" @ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html
  var jclassAddress2NameMap = {};
  function getNativeAddress(idx) {
    return env.handle.readPointer().add(idx * pSize).readPointer();
  }
  // intercepting FindClass to populate Map<address, jclass>
  Interceptor.attach(getNativeAddress(FindClassIndex), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
      jclassAddress2NameMap[args[0]] = args[1].readCString();
    }
  });
  // RegisterNative(jClass*, .., JNINativeMethod *methods[nMethods], uint nMethods) // https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/master/include_jni/jni.h#977
  Interceptor.attach(getNativeAddress(RegisterNatives), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
      for (var i = 0, nMethods = parseInt(args[3]); i < nMethods; i++) {
        /*
          https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/master/include_jni/jni.h#129
          typedef struct {
             const char* name;
             const char* signature;
             void* fnPtr;
          } JNINativeMethod;
        */
        var structSize = pSize * 3; // = sizeof(JNINativeMethod)
        var methodsPtr = ptr(args[2]);
        var signature = methodsPtr.add(i * structSize + pSize).readPointer();
        var fnPtr = methodsPtr.add(i * structSize + (pSize * 2)).readPointer(); // void* fnPtr
        var jClass = jclassAddress2NameMap[args[0]].split('/');
        console.log('\x1b[3' + '6;01' + 'm', JSON.stringify({
          module: DebugSymbol.fromAddress(fnPtr)['moduleName'], // https://www.frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#debugsymbol
          package: jClass.slice(0, -1).join('.'),
          class: jClass[jClass.length - 1],
          method: methodsPtr.readPointer().readCString(), // char* name
          signature: signature.readCString(), // char* signature TODO Java bytecode signature parser { Z: 'boolean', B: 'byte', C: 'char', S: 'short', I: 'int', J: 'long', F: 'float', D: 'double', L: 'fully-qualified-class;', '[': 'array' } https://github.com/skylot/jadx/blob/master/jadx-core/src/main/java/jadx/core/dex/nodes/parser/SignatureParser.java
          address: fnPtr
        }), '\x1b[39;49;00m');
      }
    }
  });
}

Java.perform(RevealNativeMethods);
```

Comment: Is this a general purpose solution (do I need to modify it for my binary)? I am also reverse engineering a heavily obfuscated shared object that came from an APK. In my case, the only export defined in the shared object is JNI_OnLoad. I'm certain that within this function RegisterNatives is called, though again it's heavily obfuscated and difficult to tell how the arguments are passed. :(

Answer (score 8):

> which I assume is build with -fvisibility=hidden because the only export is JNI_OnLoad, no JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app_Bar_foo which means public native int foo does not follow the naming convention.

This is **not always true**, because you can also use `RegisterNatives` inside `JNI_OnLoad` to declare your JNI methods not following the typical naming convention.

```
/*
 * Register several native methods for one class.
 */
static int registerNativeMethods(JNIEnv* env, const char* className,
                                 JNINativeMethod* gMethods, int numMethods)
{
    jclass clazz;
    clazz = env->FindClass(className);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        ALOGE("Native registration unable to find class '%s'", className);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    if (env->RegisterNatives(clazz, gMethods, numMethods) < 0) {
        ALOGE("RegisterNatives failed for '%s'", className);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

> What is the process when foo is invoked ?

Maybe you can take a look at this article https://arophix.com/2017/12/17/andoid-jni-summary/

> How can I extract the address of foo ? ( I'm familiar with Frida )

I am not sure about Frida, For Cydia Substrate, you can use `dlsym` to find the address of specified symbol of `.so`, e.g.

```
void* find_symbol(const char* libraryname, const char* symbolname)
{
    void *imagehandle = dlopen(libraryname, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    if (imagehandle != NULL) {
        void * sym = dlsym(imagehandle, symbolname);
        if (sym != NULL) {
            LOGE("symbol (%s) is found at address %p (%p) in lib %s", symbolname, sym, &sym, libraryname);
            return sym;
        } else {
            LOGE("find_symbol() can't find symblo (%s).", symbolname);
            return NULL;
        }
    } else {
        LOGE("dlopen error: %s, when opening lib %s",dlerror(), libraryname);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Here is the full tutorial for using Cydia Substrate  https://arophix.com/2017/11/30/android-substrate-hooking/ ,

**--------Updates--------**

**Edit #1**

For Frida, maybe it is similar. Here is a reference link which may help with your case. https://www.notsosecure.com/instrumenting-native-android-functions-using-frida/

**Edit #2**

For a complete Github tutorial project about Frida based hooking, please refer to [Using Apktool and Frida to do reverse engineering on Android Apk.](https://github.com/russell-shizhen/DecompileApk).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! upvoted. updated my main question w/ Frida script with the same logic which did not work, hopefully someone encountered the same issue and might help before I approve. Message Sent via `arophix.com/contact`

Comment: @IddoE Just add one Frida reference for your information.

Comment: The reference is related to when the JNI naming convention is default, e.g Java_com..MethodName

Comment: As I  know, many security companies applies security techniques to the native .so libraries, e.g. hiding the symbols as much as possible, obfuscating the exported symbols and eventually adding some protection over the JNI bridge. All of these makes the reverse engineering work more and more difficult.

Comment: but when the Java side of the APK invokes `public native String foo` this means the address of native function foo is stored some where in some data structure in memory which I want to find, I can give many real life applications, couple I'm practicing on right now

Comment: Indeed, theoretically you should be able to find the address of any symbols.