# Android Studio, Adding Native C++ Code via JNI to a Second Activity of an Android App

Tags: c++, android-studio, kotlin, java-native-interface

I'm using Android Studio to build an Android app.  I'm using Kotlin, and I'm using C++ code, i.e. native C++ that I interface with using JNI.    I'm able to do this in the MainActivity, because Android Studio offers this build in their setup.  However, **I can't figure out a way to call native C++ functions from a second empty activity that I created.**   Does anyone know how to set up a second activity to access native C++ code?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just make sure that you follow [the required naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470463/what-is-the-naming-convention-for-java-native-interface-method-and-module-name/32473938#32473938), and that the library has been loaded by the time you attempt to call the native functions.

Comment: Please show code and error messages after you add a `native` method to your second activity.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your response.  For the record, I ended up using a lateinit var to MainActivity in a companion object in the MainActivity, and I referenced it in the second activity.  That worked to access my native c++ functions.

Comment: @Botje -- I ended up getting it working as described to Michael.