There is no java function in shared object(lib) file
in this Java code there are many functions to use through the native-lib file and this is the calling code
static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    public final native byte[] f(Context context, String m10);

    public final native String m(Context context, int p02, int p12);

    public final native String ss(Context context, String raw, int p02, int p12);

    public final native void u(Context context, String str, byte[] bArr);

    public final native void u2(Context context, String str, byte[] bArr, int i, int i10);

When I opened the native-lib file using ghidra and then searched for the u2 function, I did not find any result, as you will see in the picture. Search on ghidra
So I tried using alternative tools like ida but it didn't work. So is there anyone know why is native function haven't seen in ghidra?

Here is the image https://i.sstatic.net/D6hQif4E.jpg

Don't use images for text information like code and logs.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470463/what-is-the-naming-convention-for-java-native-interface-method-and-module-name.
